# amcharts Overlay legend on a chart

Tags: amcharts

How can I overlay the legend on a column chart without?

Would I need to use absolute positioning? If so, could someone provide an example?

Please see the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-legend-in-an-external-container/

I managed this by placing the legend in another container, then setting an absolute property and overlaying the div.

`var legendContainer = am4core.create("legenddiv", am4core.Container)`

`chart.legend.parent = legendContainer;`